# Is it possible to download or access the files from StorSimple using Java

Tags: java, azure

Is it possible to download or access the files from StorSimple  using Java.I am able to download files from azure container using Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storsimple/)  StorSimple predominantly use .NET for data migration .

Refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storsimple/storsimple-data-manager-overview) to download data from StorSimple using .NET .